# Run "grails shiro-quick-start --prefix=org.example.Shiro" with Grails 2.3

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, shiro

I seem to be unable to run

```
    grails shiro-quick-start --prefix=org.example.Shiro
```

in the terminal when I'm on Grails 2.3. Anyone know why that is?

I have a feeling it is to do with me being unable to run

```
    grails install-plugin shiro
```

also as it says

```
Since Grails 2.3, it is no longer possible to install plugins using the install-plugin command.
Plugins must be declared in the grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy file.

Example:
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   ...
   plugins {
      compile ":shiro:1.2.0"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of grails no longer supports install-plugin command, and all plugins must be configured in BuildConfig.groovy and not application.properties.

Try this

In your BuildConfig.groovy

```
plugins {
  compile (":shiro:1.2.0") { excludes "servlet-api" }
```

}

You need to exclude dependency to servlet-api, see my comment above and this [link](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHE-33)

Next, start grails console and use refresh-dependencies command, and then compile.
After that exist grails console and start it again. (I have to do this after installing new plugin, if i want to execute a gant script from that plugin)

Try running shiro-quick-start command again, it should work definitely.

BTW, you may want to give a look to [nimble plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/nimble), it extends functionality provided by shiro plugin, and gives you ready to use UI etc, it may save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems to have worked now. Will take a look at nimble also :)

Comment: Thank you. I have same problems and your solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Right, so add the dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy` as the message says. Then run `grails compile` to get everything resolved, and then the Shiro script.

Comment: I have it added to the BuildConfig and compiled. I just get this back                | Script 'ShiroQuickStart' not found, did you mean:
   1) Stats
   2) DbmListLocks
   3) InstallJQuery
   4) DbmRollbackSql
   5) TestApp
> Please make a selection or enter Q to quit:

Comment: Did you add `compile ":shiro:1.2.0"` to the existing `plugins` section? It works fine for me, but the shiro and cache plugins apparently aren't compatible, so I had to remove the cache plugin entry that was already there. Once I did that I ran compile and was able to run `shiro-quick-start`. If this doesn't work, please edit your question and show the `plugins` section from your `BuildConfig.groovy`

Comment: @BurtBeckwith excluding 'servlet-api' from shiro would make it work with cache plugin, Apache shiro has dependency on servlet api 2.x (Weird), which causes cache to fail at compile time, because it needs servlet 3.x in classpath. See http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHE-33